# How does vitamix blender works

Tags: modeling, video

I want to know how does a Vitamix blender works? and its worth with money? I saw there are few vitamix model price around $400 to $500.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about physical blenders, will blender.se is exclusively about the usage of the **3D content creation software Blender**.

Comment: Maybe read the rules on the [seasoned advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (cooking) stackexchange and possibly post the question there.

Comment: I *need* this text as a description for Blender.SE site :). Please. Just for one day.

Comment: The tags tho :)

Answer (score 2):

I want this tagline.
@Pamela, no hard feelings, this is just too good.

[image]

Comment: The vitamix addon can do fracturing, particles and liquids in real-time!

Comment: Don't forget that Vitamix oven though. Great for baking and stuff...